# ext js tab panel: which tab will be loaded by default?

Tags: extjs

In extjs, in a tabpanel, if there are multiple tabs, which one of them will be loaded by default when the panel is initialised? The first one? Is there a way to set this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    activeTab: 0,     ///  ------- here is something what you looking for
    items: [{
        title: 'Tab 1',
        html: 'A simple tab'
    },{
        title: 'Tab 2',
        html: 'Another one'
    }]
});
```

I strongly belive what in this case first one...

Answer (score 3):

When initializing an `Ext.TabPanel` the parameter `activeTab` is set to `undefined`. As far as I can tell, *ExtJS* interprets this as *do not open any of the tabs when showing the tabpanel the first time*. Even though no tabs are opened by default, the row of tabs will still be visible and fully functional.

You can set the parameter `activeTab` equal to the index of the tab you would like to see opened when the tabpanel is shown.

In the fine example given by **bensiu**, `activeTab` is set to 0, which will cause **Tab 1** to be visible when the tabpanel is shown.